# Sequelize Op.or within Op.and for nested operations

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I want to make the condition

(A AND B) And (C Or D Or E Or F)

When I try to do

```
where: {
  [Op.and]: [{
    A,
    B,
    [Op.or]: [{
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F
     }]
  }]
}
```

This operation will just return A And B AND C AND D AND E AND F, for some reason Op.or just fails within Op.and. Maybe there is a better way to do the logical operation, would anyone know what do?

Comment: Each condition will go within separate object. You are passing all the condition in one object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below,

```
where: {
  [Op.and]: [
    {
      A
    },
    {
      B
    },
    {
      [Op.or]: [{
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F
     }]
    }
  ]
}
```

See the syntax for `[Op.and]` [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators).

Comment: I figured out a solution shortly after posting, I'm sure your method works though so I'll give you the check. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by getting rid of the arrays, for some reason they were interfering in the interpretation. I guess you're not allowed to wrap Op.or with Op.and

```
            [Op.and]: {
                A',
                B,
                [Op.or]: {
                    C,
                    D,
                    E,
                    F
                },
            }
```